# Globally suppress Code Analysis warning CA1704 across a project or assembly?

Tags: .net, code-analysis, suppression

I have several Code Analysis `CA1704:IdentifiersShouldBeSpelledCorrectly` warnings that I want to suppress. Basically, they refer to the company name which is deemed to be spelled incorrectly.

The company name is part of several namespaces in my project, and in order to suppress all of the warnings I need to add a lot of suppressions to the `GlobalSuppressions` file. Is there any way to suppress all of these warnings in a single line in the `GlobalSuppressions` file to keep my `GlobalSuppressions` file from becoming overly cluttered?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't suppress many warnings with a single suppression, but when it comes to unknown or deliberate deviant spelling, the best solution is to add a [custom Code Analysis dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/how-to-customize-the-code-analysis-dictionary?view=vs-2017).

Answer (score 2):

You could add the company name to CustomDictionary.xml